# Object has it's old values even after update

Tags: java, caching

I make caching for objects at the start of my application, this object is the result of parsing xml file and store its content in an `ArrayList`.

Now I update the data in the xml file, but the object in the cache still have the old values, here's the code which I call the cached object:

```
  ObjectsCaching objCache = ObjectsCaching.getObjectsCaching();
    Cache cache = objCache.getMemoryCache();
    List<FormPorperties> formList = null;  //to obtain form properties from xml file whether form cashed object or through parsing xml file
    if (cache.get("formValidators") == null) {//if object is not cashed in memory
        try {
            InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("FormFieldsNames.xml");
            // list of FormPropereties, each formProperties object contain form name
            // and HashMap of field with its validation
            formList = XMLFormParsing.getFormsProperties(fis); //singelton class
            cache.put("formProperties", formList);  //cash object
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in parsing FormFieldsNames file ", ex);
        } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in parsing FormFieldsNames file ", ex);
        }

    } else {
       formList = (List<FormPorperties>) cache.get("formProperties");
   }
```

I tried to remove the check code

```
 if (cache.get("formValidators") == null)
```

to force application to parse the file, but it still read the old content

The content of xml file is the forms names and each form fields, I use this way to make validation for form field at the server side.

here's the conetn

```
 <form name="groupAdditoinEditionForm">
 <fieldName > groupEname </fieldName>
 <fieldName > groupAname </fieldName>
 </form>

 <form name="userAdditionFrom">
 <fieldName > userName </fieldName>
  <fieldName > country </fieldName>
 <fieldName > faxNo </fieldName>
 <fieldName > email </fieldName>
 <fieldName > confirmEmail </fieldName>
 <fieldName > accessControl </fieldName>
 <fieldName > lang </fieldName>
<fieldName > group </fieldName>
 </form>
```

I add the first tag to the xml file, but parser still read the old values!!

Answer (score 0):

Well this may be part of the problem:

```
// Uses key "formValidators"
if (cache.get("formValidators") == null))
...
// Uses key "formProperties"
formList = (List<FormPorperties>) cache.get("formProperties");
```

Surely you should be using the same key both times? Or (ideally) just fetching once and then only going through the repopulation part if `formList` is still null... something like this:

```
// Adjust "key" to whatever cache key you *really* want to use
List<FormPorperties> formList = (List<FormPorperties>) cache.get("key");
if (formList == null) {
    // Populate and cache
}
```

Now as for why the values aren't being updated... are you doing anything to invalidate the cache? If not, what do you expect would make it update the values? Does any part of your system watch the XML files in order to remove stale entries from the cache?

Comment: I modify the content of the xml file, I add another form with it's property.

Comment: @Alaa: I don't know what you mean by "I add another form with its property" - but what makes you think the cache will be invalidated?

Comment: @Alaa: You still seem to be missing the point. You're changing the file, but expecting the cache to notice that somehow. Do you have any code watching to see if the file has changed? If not, you shouldn't *expect* anything to notice that - it will just read the cached version.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, how can I remove elements from cashe?

Comment: @Alaa: You'll need to either check for the last modified time of the file each time you fetch the value from the cache, or have a separate thread using a file system monitor to notice changes. I'm not sure what facilities Java provides for monitoring for changes though...

Comment: I tried this way,http://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml but doesn't work !!

Comment: @Alaa: That's a plugin cache. It has *nothing* to do with the cache you're creating in your code.